# How do I dig below the magma seas?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I dug right to the magma seas in Dwarf Fortress, but now I'm stuck.

Below the layer I'm on now is only semi molten rock which I can't dig through. I know that there are adamantine veins but I can't access them because I'm surrounded by magma or semi molten rock on this level. Is there any way I can dig down anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't dig across to get to the adamantine, you'll just have to start from above the magma sea and dig straight down once you've located the adamantine veins. And if you haven't already: breach into the magma sea by channeling to make lower levels visible.

To quote the Simpsons: "No, dig up, stupid." :)

Comment: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Semi-molten_rock in later versions you can dig down through semi molten rock. But it is pretty deadly and 'hack'-like.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you channel through the SMR and then use water to solidify a section of magma into obsidian? This would allow you to dig down another layer, pour more water, etc., until you make it through the magma.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I've heard of people doing this but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: You can't dig through SMR at all.

Comment: That's true, Arda Xi. I think the proper method is to channel down until you breach into the magma sea from above, then pour water onto it until you have a solid layer of obsidian to dig down through. Again, I've never tried but this in principle could work.

Comment: I've heard that you can get through SMR, what you do is you have to get beside it and then carve an upward ramp. I'm not sure if this works, but I've heard it can be done.

Comment: You can dig into SMR if you can't see it.  That means you can only dig into it from below, or from above if the floor above it isn't SMR.  Every method I've heard of for channeling through SMR involved the death of multiple dwarves (one for every tile mined).